# PHP assign first not null, set and not empty value

Tags: php, variables

i partially solved with the line above to setup a variable from different others got by the POST method

```
$myvar= $_POST['myvar_a'] ?: $_POST['myvar_b'] ?: $_POST['myvar'] ?: NULL;
```

but i need take care of not set and empty value.
when not set myvar_a and myvar_b take myvar, otherwise force NULL because i have to set it up in the current execution.
really i achieved it with nested if then else like this pseudo

```
if isset and !empty myvar = myvar_a
else ...
```

but i would like shorten the code. any tips?

Comment: Well...technically, I suppose you could do it all on one line by dropping in ternary statements - but readability would go out the window. How short are you trying to make your code?

Comment: i just wanted to shorten the isset and not empty part, but i think i need it because i can't give a not set value to a function

Comment: If your code isn't so verbose to the point where it adversely affects readability/maintainability, I wouldn't be too concerned here. Trying to squish everything together may be a bit hard to read in some cases: `$myvar = (isset($_POST['myvar_a']) && !empty($_POST['myvar_a'])) ? $_POST['myvar_a'] : (isset($_POST['myvar_b']) && !empty($_POST['myvar_b'])) ? $_POST['myvar_b'] : (isset($_POST['myvar']) && !empty($_POST['myvar'])) ? $_POST['myvar'] : NULL;`

Comment: its a nice idea but dont looks really a shortening. its like my if then else mentioned before. i think i will stop thinking about this